# Get size of m3u8 video by URL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, m3u8

I tried to fetch the file size of m3u8 video before downloading by its url. but its not giving me the file size instead its giving me fixed number which is not file size.

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: nil];
    long long size = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"file size %lld",size);
```

Comment: m3u8 is just a text file with links to video segments. You need to loop over every segment and accumulate the sizes.

Comment: any reference please @szatmary

Comment: Yes see, Rfc 8216

Comment: i got this after parsing m3u8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjTaf.png , is it possible to find size by Extinf ?